# Why is this expect shell script to ssh into and reboot cisco appliances failing?

Tags: shell, ssh, expect, restart, cisco

Created this simple script to perform a reboot on a Cisco (Telepresence) CTS1300, 1000 and 3000 codecs.  The goal is to restart a bunch of these units weekly through the use of a cron. I am using Cygwin, and here's the expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh AdminUser@123.123.123.123
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "MyPassword\r"
expect "*admin:*"
"send -- "utils system restart\r"
expect -exact "Are you sure you want to perform a System Restart ?\r
Enter \"yes\" to Restart the System or any other key to abort\r
continue: "
send -- "yes\r"
expect "*admin:*"
send -- "quit\r"
expect eof
```

The output is:

```
superuser@SUPERPC ~/ctspsswd 
./restartall2
spawn ssh AdminUser@123.123.123.123
AdminUser@123.123.123.123's password:
Command Line Interface is starting up, please wait ...

Welcome to the TelePresence Command Line Interface (version 1.1)
admin:utils system restart
Are you sure you want to perform a System Restart ?
Enter "yes" to Restart the System or any other key to abort
continue: s
The System Restart has been aborted
admin:quit
Connection to 123.123.123.123 closed.
```

For some weird reason, it only sends "s", which aborts the system restart.

I tried using `#!/bin/bash` type scripting and output is similar.

I tried using wild chars for expect `"*continue:*"` and still similar output.

I tried using `autoexpect` and same exact thing happens. Autoexpect script looks very similar to my script, only is more specific to each character I typed.

I tried sending `yes` immediately after sending utils system restart, and the result was simply the equivalent of a `\r`.

Is there something I'm missing?  Otherwise, I'll create a script that will use interact for the `yes` portion.

Comment: I can't see why the 2 chars are being eaten. Try sending `"  yes\r"` (with 2 spaces before "y"). Also try adding `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script (I wonder if the big string is actually matching -- do you notice a 10 second delay before the "s" is sent?)

Comment: If I set two spaces before y, the output shows just an y, then goes to abort the system restart. There is no delay, and the string is matched, I've also been able to match it by using "*continue". I have heard from googling that expect may misbehave under Cygwin. I'm gonna get a laptop under fedora and try the same script.

Comment: exp_interal 1: 
send: sending "yes\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*admin:*"? no
s
expect: does "s" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*admin:*"? no

Comment: same exact behavior on a OSX 10.8.2, no point on testing furthermore on other platforms.

Comment: I resolved just now by adding this: set send_human {.1 .3 .05 2 2} send -h "yes\r". This allows the slow down of the input buffer. similar with set -s